# How to deny a user to login to Ubuntu desktop? (ssh access is allowed)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions

I wanted to have a group of users that are allowed to login via ssh, but denied to login to desktop on Ubuntu 16.04.

I've created a user without home directory and that denied the user to login via desktop, while having access to ssh and that's working fine. But, I don't know is it a good way to do that? or is there any particular way to restrict users from logging in to desktop, while they can login via ssh?